# How to convert Django Ninja errors into Schema that can be used in the ninja api respose

Tags: django-ninja

I am using Django Ninja to develop APIs

```
from ninja import Schema
from ninja.errors import HttpError, ValidationError

class MyOutSchema(Schema)

@router.get("/", response={200: MyOutSchema, 404:XXX, 429:XXX, 400:XXX})
def my_api(request, params)
{
// Some code that may raise HttpError and ValidationError
}
```

What can I use in place of `XXX` ?

I cannot use HttpError or ValidationError since the documentation then fails to get the correct schema from Ninja

How can I convert the Ninja error objects to "Schem"able classes ?

I tried using `HttpError` in the response dictionary and I was expecting it to work.

The documentation generation failed.

```
[14:13:01] [DJANGO] @router.get(
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]      ^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/router.py", line 239, in decorator
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     self.add_api_operation(
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/router.py", line 288, in add_api_operation
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     path_view.add_operation(
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 306, in add_operation
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     operation = OperationClass(
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 75, in __init__
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     self.response_models = self._create_response_model_multiple(response)
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 241, in _create_response_model_multiple
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     result[code] = self._create_response_model(model)
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 248, in _create_response_model
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     return type("NinjaResponseSchema", (Schema,), attrs)
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "/home/Work/web-framework/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/schema.py", line 145, in __new__
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]     result = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]              ^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO] ^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/main.py", line 197, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 506, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 557, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/fields.py", line 831, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
[14:13:01] [DJANGO]   File "pydantic/validators.py", line 765, in find_validators
[14:13:01] [DJANGO] RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'ninja.errors.ValidationError'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

Also I tried using `None` hoping that it would default to some nice Ninja error schema but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Django Ninja can do this more automatically for you if you just raise `HttpError` as an exception with the corresponding error message, instead of returning anything. You don't really need to handle this using schemas yourself.

Try something like this instead:

```
from ninja.errors import HttpError
from ninja.schema import Schema


class MyOutSchema(Schema):
    something: str


@router.get("/", response=MyOutSchema)
def my_api(request, params):
    if not params_make_sense(params):
        raise HttpError(400, "Example error message")

    return {
        "something": "daddara",
    }
```

**Note that it is using `raise` instead of `return`**.

Using [`httpie`](https://httpie.io/) to test the endpoint from the command line, the client output might look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Language: is
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2023 19:24:50 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.6
Vary: Accept-Language
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "detail": "Example error message"
}
```